# Convert (not necessarily well-formed) HTML into Associative Array

Tags: php, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<table id="metadata_content_table"><tr class="metadata_row"><td
class="metadata_label">Title</td><td class="metadata_value"><span dir=ltr>PHP
Reference: Beginner to Intermediate PHP5</span></td></tr><tr
class="metadata_row"><td class="metadata_label"><span
dir=ltr>Author</span></td><td class="metadata_value"><a class="primary"
href="https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&amp;tbm=bks&amp;q=inauthor:%22Mario+Lurig%22&amp;source=gbs_metadata_r&amp;cad=6"><span
dir=ltr>Mario Lurig</span></a></td></tr><tr class="metadata_row"><td
class="metadata_label"><span dir=ltr>Publisher</span></td><td
class="metadata_value"><span dir=ltr>Mario Lurig, 2008</span></td></tr><tr
class="metadata_row"><td class="metadata_label"><span
dir=ltr>ISBN</span></td><td class="metadata_value"><span dir=ltr>143571590X,
9781435715905</span></td></tr><tr class="metadata_row"><td
class="metadata_label"><span dir=ltr>Length</span></td><td
class="metadata_value"><span dir=ltr>164 pages</span></td></tr><tr
class="metadata_row"><td class="metadata_label"><span
dir=ltr>Subjects</span></td><td class="metadata_value"><div
style="display:inline" itemscope
itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a class="primary"
href="https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&amp;tbm=bks&amp;q=subject:%22Computers%22"
itemprop="url" dir=ltr><span
itemprop="title">Computers</span></a></div>&nbsp;&#8250;&nbsp;<div
style="display:inline" itemscope
itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a class="primary"
href="https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&amp;tbm=bks&amp;q=subject:%22Computers+Programming%22"
itemprop="url" dir=ltr><span
itemprop="title">Programming</span></a></div>&nbsp;&#8250;&nbsp;<div
style="display:inline" itemscope
itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a class="primary"
href="https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&amp;tbm=bks&amp;q=subject:%22Computers+Programming+Object+Oriented%22"
itemprop="url" dir=ltr><span itemprop="title">Object
Oriented</span></a></div><br><br><a class="primary"
href="https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&amp;tbm=bks&amp;q=subject:%22Computers+/+General%22&amp;source=gbs_metadata_r&amp;cad=6"><span
dir=ltr>Computers / General</span></a><br/><a class="primary"
href="https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&amp;tbm=bks&amp;q=subject:%22Computers+/+Programming+/+Object+Oriented%22&amp;source=gbs_metadata_r&amp;cad=6"><span
dir=ltr>Computers / Programming / Object Oriented</span></a></td></tr><tr
class="metadata_row"><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr><tr
class="metadata_row"><td class="metadata_label"><span dir=ltr>Export
Citation</span></td><td class="metadata_value"><a class="gb-button "
href="https://books.google.com/books/download/PHP_Reference_Beginner_to_Intermediate_P.bibtex?id=noi76uKOJ5wC&amp;output=bibtex"><span
dir=ltr>BiBTeX</span></a>&nbsp;<a class="gb-button "
href="https://books.google.com/books/download/PHP_Reference_Beginner_to_Intermediate_P.enw?id=noi76uKOJ5wC&amp;output=enw"><span
dir=ltr>EndNote</span></a>&nbsp;<a class="gb-button "
href="https://books.google.com/books/download/PHP_Reference_Beginner_to_Intermediate_P.ris?id=noi76uKOJ5wC&amp;output=ris"><span
dir=ltr>RefMan</span></a></td></tr></table>
```

As you can see, the HTML is not well-formed XML. eg. the span elements have attribute values that are not in quotation marks.

When I try to parse the above XML:
$ob= simplexml_load_string($xml);
The function does not work (returns FALSE).

I am aiming to convert the HTML into an associative array. With XML, the following code works:

```
$ob= simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json  = json_encode($xml);
        $configData = json_decode($json, true);
```

How can I achieve the same result with HTML that is not well-formed XML?